# CocaPods importing AFNetworking but not OHAttributedLabel

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am using CocaPods to add `AFNetowrking` and `OHAttributedLabel` into my project. I installed both of the libraries. `AFNetworking` is importing just fine in my project. But `OHAttributedLabel` isn't. I am not sure why!

## Podfile

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
 
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'OHAttributedLabel'
```

After installing both the libraries, when I import

```
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"
#import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
```

I do not get any errors and everything works just fine

but when I am trying to import

```
#import <OHAttributedLabel/OHAttributedLabel.h>
#import <OHAttributedLabel/NSAttributedString+Attributes.h>
#import <OHAttributedLabel/OHASBasicMarkupParser.h>
```

I am getting

`'OHAttributedLabel/OHAttributedLabel.h' file not found`

error

## pod install output

```
Resolving dependencies of `./Podfile'
Updating spec repositories

Cocoapods 0.17.0.rc7 is available.

Resolving dependencies for target `default' (iOS 6.0)
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (1.1.0)
Installing OHAttributedLabel (3.4.1)
Generating support files
```

The suggestion says

> Make sure your project is using the Pods.xcconfig. To check this
> select your project file, then select it in the second pane again and
> open the Info section in the third pane. Under configurations you
> should select Pods.xcconfig for each configurations requiring your
> installed pods.

I am not sure where to add this. This is how my configurations look like

[image]

## Edit

After copying pods.xcconfig

[image]

Comment: can you be more specific and maybe also include your `Podfile`?

Comment: and what's happening? Does it give you any error?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella yes I added more details. I am sorry for not being specific

Comment: I just tried to do the same thing and it works flawlessly. Have you tried to clean your project and reopen it?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella can you please elaborate on that? how should I clean my project?

Comment: I did do Command-Option-Shift-K, but I am still getting the error

Comment: CMD+SHIFT+K will clean your project

Comment: Do you see `OHAttributedLabel` folder under the `Pods` group in the `Pods` project of your workspace?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella yes. also,after the clean project I closed my xcode and opened it again, now I am getting errors for AFNetowrking as well

Comment: Try importing `#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>` and `#import <OHAttributedLabel/OHAttributedLabel.h>` in your `<APP_NAME>-Prefix.pch` file. Also what's the output of `pod install` when you run it?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella please have a look at the edit, also import those in pch doesnt help either

Comment: try following point 2. from this FAQs https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Creating-a-project-that-uses-CocoaPods

Comment: @GabrielePetronella can you please tell me how do I "Check if the pod header files are correctly symlinked in Pods/Headers"?

Comment: In the `Build Settings` of the Pods projects's Target there should be an entry which looks like this http://cl.ly/image/1j1F3n2m1s2J

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Thank you so much for explaining that, and yes it has `"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/AFNetworking" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/OHAttributedLabel"` in it

Comment: have you tried the rest of the FAQ suggestions?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella please have a look at my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the proper configurations set.

You project's info should look like this

[image]

Comment: You should have a file name `Pods.xcconfig` in your project. Can you see it?

Comment: Looks like, now you should be able to see the configuration sets `Pods` in the Info pane of your project settings

Comment: is there a way to completely remove CocaPods and add it again? do you think that would help?

Comment: You can try to update the CocoaPods gem and run pod install again

Comment: at this point I would suggest to try creating a whole new project, just linking the two libraries and see whether it works. I think something nasty is going on with you current project's settings.

Comment: Yeah thats what I ended up doing. I dont know I must have messed something up along the way. From now on Snapshots will be used before any major change :P

Answer (score 1):

This might sound silly, but are you trying to build and run the Pods project in your workspace rather than your own app project? I've been guilty of that many times and have seen similar errors!

Comment: Adam, nope I am running my app :) not Pods

Comment: Ha, worth a shot. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You encounter these errors when installing pods on a project that has custom compiler/linker flags like HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS and/or OTHER_LDFLAGS (via the 'Header Search Paths' or 'Other linker flags' target settings). These settings will override your pods configuration file, since configuration files have lower priority than target settings.

To fix this you will need to add $(inherited) to the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS and other changed flags in your target build settings.  Just append it to the end like this:
[image: modifying build settings]

Also to note, when you installed the pods with pod install it should warn you with messages like this if you have set custom flags that would be affected:

> [!] From now on use `myprojectname`.
>
> [!] The target `myprojectname [Debug]` overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS`
>   build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.
>
> [!] The target `myprojectname [Debug]` overrides the
>   `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.
>
> [!] The target `myprojectname [Debug - Release]` overrides the
>   `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.
>
> [!] The target `myprojectname [Debug - Release]` overrides the
>   `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your taget Build Settings -> Other linker flags -> double click . Add $(inherited) to a new line .